# Blurred desktop with Nouveau drivers for nVidia GPU at lower resolution

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, gnome

A friend is having desktop with on-board nVidia graphics (Its an asus motherboard without discrete GPU). I've made clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 and than installed GNOME shell. And I had following issues.

- The shell graphics were looking sluggish (white bars on top panel, etc).
- screen alignment was improper.

So I installed "recommended" nVidia drivers from Additional Drivers utility. After installation and reboot, I got

- Top panel and other shell elements looked fine.
- Screen alignment also got proper at native resolution of monitor (1366x768).

But GNOME shell performance got sloppy and animations were not smooth, and viewing Activities overview looked like shell is freezed.

So I uninstalled the drivers, and reverted back to Nouveau, but I was surprized that shell top panel looks fine even after removal of drivers, and even shell animations are smooth and perfect. But again I have screen alignment improper and portion of desktop was outside screen area at monitor's native resolution.

So I opened Displays and changed the resolution to **1280x720** (which is not the resolution I have for the same system in its Windows 7 installation, 1366x768).

But at this resolution with no nVidia drivers installed. I have all the issues solved acccept a new one. The desktop looks little bit hazy and fonts look like little blurred. I know this usually happens when you switch to the resolution lower than the recommended. But looking at the issues I've faced with proprietary drivers, this is the best working state I've attained for the system.

**Note:** I also tried installing updated `nvidia-current` package from `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` and that also didn't worked and at some point (may be due to my mistake) made system unbootable to Ubuntu, so I got is back to working by purging the ppa and deleting `xorg.conf` file that the driver utility created.

Comment: are you still having the issue or has it been resolved through system updates?

Comment: @MarkRooney: Well, I've falled back graphics drivers to Nouveau after uninstalling nVidia. The Desktop is no longer looking blurred, but GNOME shell animations are occasionally sloppy. Someone who's moderating AU, is free to close this question though my problem is not fixed completely with nVidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: I've posted your comment as an answer. Looking on the net it appears there is issues with the proprietary nvidia driver and gnome shell, the latest release 295.20 fixes many issues but there is a bug with gnome-search crashing while using it.

Answer (score 2):

OP has resolved the issue themselves by uninstalling nvidia driver

> Well, I've falled back graphics drivers to Nouveau after uninstalling
>   nVidia. The Desktop is no longer looking blurred, but GNOME shell
>   animations are occasionally sloppy. Someone who's moderating AU, is
>   free to close this question though my problem is not fixed completely
>   with nVidia proprietary drivers